# Android App Getting Killed on Intent Launch

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-package-managers

I have an app which is kept hidden from the launcher. Now I want to open the app from the dialer. So I have a BroadcastReceiver where I am handling things.

1) First I show the app,

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context,
                SplashActivity.class);
        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

2) Then launch an Intent,

```
Intent launcher = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
                    launcher.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(launcher);
```

3) Then I am hiding the app again,

```
ComponentName componentName2 = new ComponentName(context,
                SplashActivity.class);
        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentName2,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**The Problem**

The Intent launch is successful but the app is getting killed after a few seconds. But the problem doesn't occur if I launch any other activity other than the SplashActivity. What is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: If you are getting error then post your logcat so we can figure it out.

Comment: @Apurva No error. Just the app gets killed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<activity-alias>` tag in Android manifest for launcher activity. change in your manifest for launcher activity like as below:-

```
        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.watever.SplashActivityAlias"
            android:targetActivity="com.watever.SplashActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

and in code where where you are showing and hiding app just use Alias Name which is used in manifest like in above manifest alias name is SplashActivityAlias so use SplashActivityAlias instead of SplashActivity in both conditions where you are showing and hiding app.
        By doing above thing you can able to hide your app icon with
 setComponent EnabledSetting method using Alias name and you can launch your main activity which is splash activity by using dialer

> For hiding app

```
ComponentName componentName2 = new ComponentName("com.packagename",
                "com.packagename.HideAppActivity");
        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentName2,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: To show hide app icon use AliasName and to launch app use targetActivity Name which SplashActivity

Comment: The app is not getting hidden after using the alias.

Comment: I pasted the alias XML is manifest and changed the component cod e like this,String packageName = context.getPackageName();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(packageName,
                                                packageName + ".SplashActivityAlias");

Comment: Are you sure because at my side its hiding the app icon. Make sure you have pasted the same intent filters which i have pasted here in manifest for the activity alias

Comment: Yes I have pasted the same as you gave me. Can you please post you code which is hiding the app icon? It will be a real help for me.

Comment: Its working now. Thank you. But you forgot to mention that I needed to remove the LAUNCHER category from my Splash Activity.